# Why doesn't `{}.toString.apply(array)` work?

Tags: javascript

Usually, when I want to check the type of an object (whether it's an array, a NodeList, or whatever), I use the following:

```
var arr = [] // I don't do this, but it's for the sake of the example
var obj = {}
obj.toString.apply(arr) // This works
```

The question is: why can I *not* do the following?

```
var arr = []
{}.toString.apply(arr) // Syntax error: Unexpected token .
```

I don't get where the syntax error is.

I can do something approaching with `[]` though, the following works:

```
var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('foo')
[].forEach.call(nodeList, function(bar) { console.log(bar) }) // Works
```

So... I'm confused.

Comment: you forgot () in toString() ?

Comment: Nope, see @Ray Toal's answer. Adding the parenthesis would lead to a syntax error (Object has no method 'apply').

Comment: Ahh.. i didn't thought that, it's correct

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you begin a line with `{` JavaScript thinks it starts a block statement, not an object literal.  Parenthesize it and you will be okay.

Comment: @Ray Toal - +1 but: 
`var arr = []
({}).toString.apply(arr) // TypeError: object is not a function`
To work code must contains semicolons `;` after each row 
`var arr = [];
({}).toString.apply(arr); // works OK`

Comment: I didn't use semicolons because I trust the ASI :) But of course you'd have to specify it if you start your line with a parenthesis (it's one of the edge cases).

Comment: +1 Correct.  In fact I instinctively had that in my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/58j53/ which I did not link to in the answer.  I love those missing semicolon problems in JS.  My favorite is when someone defines var f = function (...) {....} without the semicolon then follows that with a parenthesized expression (like an anonymous function activation) which is then picked up as an _argument_ to that function!

Comment: Yup, I usually code without semicolon, and once fell into this trap :-). Never again!